# Objects retrieved from HTTP GET is sorted one object at a time. How do I merge the objects, and sort them together?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm currently fetching objects from an API, which are hereafter placed in a global list, which is used by my template. 
 The data retrieved consists of two objects, with nested properties. 
 The two objects each hold a list of bookings. These bookings should be sorted by a date property. Currently i'm only able to produce a list, which sorts the first object, and afterwards sorts the next. So the result is:

(Object 1) 
Date 4 
Date 5 
Date 6
(Object 2)
Date 1
Date 2
Date 3

The resulting list should be:
(List)
Date 1
Date 2
Date 3
Date 4
Date 5
Date 6

The code that produces these results:

```
  getBand() {
    var list = []
    this.apiService
      .getBands(1)
      .subscribe((data: Band[]) => {
        data.forEach(x => {
          x.bookings.forEach(z => {
            if (x.name == "Band1") {
              this.cond = false
            } else if (x.name == "Band2") {
              this.cond = true;
            }
            list.push({
              id: z.id, title: z.title, start: new Date(z.start).toLocaleString("da-DK"),
              end: new Date(z.end).toLocaleString("da-DK"), band: x.name,
              band_member_name: x.band_Members.find(x => x.id == z.band_Member_Id).first_Name + " " + x.band_Members.find(x => x.id == z.band_Member_Id).last_Name, imageUrl: (this.cond ? ['../../../assets/img/band1.png'] : ['../../../assets/img/band2.png']),
              booking_Created_Date: new Date(z.booking_Created_Date).toLocaleString("da-DK")
            })
          })
          return this.bookingHistoryList = list.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.booking_Created_Date).getTime() - new Date(b.booking_Created_Date).getTime());
        })
      });
  }
```

How do I produce a list, in which the elements are sorted in the correct order?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: copy both list items in one list and then sort it.                                                             const list= [...list1, ...list2];

Comment: What is your html? Besides, you are sorting on each `Band` instance. Sort `list` after you looped over all `Band` instances.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Benny - I have already tried moving the return statement outside of the subscribe, which still yields the same result. My HTML consists of a "ngFor="let booking of bookingHistoryList", which creates a new card with information for each booking.